# LocalBroadcastManager...sendBroadcast(intent) how to see the stream of bytes this method sends?

Tags: java, android

How would I be able to see the stream of bytes the `LocalBroadcastManager` actually will send?

```
bytes [] sendBytes = sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Or the actual stream of bytes the listener receives?

Comment: That is automatically handle by OS. how can you see :D

Comment: The LBM doesn't send streams of bytes.  (Except in the sense that every reference value has some kind of byte representation that is normally opaque.)

Answer (score 0):

> How would I be able to see the stream of bytes the LocalBroadcastManager actually will send?

You are the one creating the `Intent` object. Look at the `Intent` object to see what you put in it.

> Or the actual stream of bytes the listener receives?

In the case of `LocalBroadcastManager`, this is the same `Intent` object that you passed to `sendBroadcast()` on the `LocalBroadcastManager`.